# data-* doesn't update after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update `data-coords` (11th line), but when I do it the code runs but the `data-coords` don't update. Why? It looks valid to me, am I missing something?

```
$(document).on('click', '.next-prev-js', function (e) {
    var item = e.target;
    if($(item).is("img") && tagging){
        var offset = $(item).offset();
        var imgid = $(item).attr("data-image-id");
        var obi = $("#blackout-image").offset();
        x = (e.clientX - offset.left);
        y = (e.clientY - offset.top);
        addTag(e.clientX - obi.left - 55, e.clientY - 55);
        saveCoords(x, y, imgid);
        $(item).attr("data-coords", x+","+y);
        tagging = false;
        $(".tag-self").text("Tag yourself");
        $("#blackout-image img").css({cursor: "pointer"});
        $("#blackout-image .face").delay(3000).fadeOut("fast");
        return false;
    }
    var action = $(item).attr("data-action");
    nextPrevImage(action);
    return false;
});
```

Here is the HTML portion (This is inside a php echo statement):

```
<a class='thumb-photo' href=''>
    <img class='thumb-img' data-coords='$x,$y' data-id='$id' data-image-id='$imid' data-file='$f' src='/user-data/images/image.php?id=$id&file=$f&height=240&width=240' width='240' height='240' />
</a>
```

**Demo**

(Don't refresh the page during this process)

If you click on one of the images, it will open in a viewer .

- On the left hover over "Where is He" and a square will show where the data-coords are (from thumbnail image)
- Next click on "Tag yourself", then click on a location in the image.
- Close the viewer by pressing "esc" or clicking on the transparent area
- Click on the image again, and mouse over "Where is He" the coords are still the old coords, but they should have been updated after you clicked on the new location

http://wows.phpsnips.com/profile.php?id=1&tab=photos

Comment: What is `tagging`, does the if-condition match? How do you see it does not update?

Comment: its a boolean value after you click on "Tag yourself" it get set to `true` so when you click the image it doesn't go to the next image (which is the default operation).

Comment: show savecoords function?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

```
   $(item).data({coords: x+","+y});
```

or

```
   $(item).data("coords", x+","+y);
```

works in jsfiddle.

You can see your data attributes with:

```
   console.log($(item).data());
```

Comment: Really? Only with "coords"? Ok, this is strange. :)

Comment: @Kaeros: No, the `data` method is not made for manipulating data attributes.

Comment: @Bergi it's true that `.data()` is not made for *manipulating* data attributes, but what's the point of doing that anyway?

Comment: @Pointy: Not sure, but the OP said he cannot see them updating - I expected a DOM inspector, yet I still don't know.

Comment: @Bergi right - `.data()` won't update the attributes, so he wouldn't see them change in that case; the point is that there's really no need for them to change. What matters is that the values originate with what's in the HTML, and update as per the JavaScript activity, and that's exactly what `.data()` will do.

Answer (score 1):

The way the `data-` attributes work is that the value gets copied into the jQuery data object on page load. After that they aren't really connected anymore. So if you change the attribute, the object **won't** update automatically. Same for the other way around.

I made a quick test to demonstrate the behavior:

**jQuery:**

```
var $d = $('div');
alert('Load: Attribute "a" gets copied to data object.\rData Attribute: ' + $d.attr('data-test') + '\rData Object: ' + $d.data('test'));

$d.attr('data-test','b');
alert('Changed attribute to "b". Attribute changed, object still "a".\rData Attribute: ' + $d.attr('data-test') + '\rData Object: ' + $d.data('test'));

$d.data('test','c');
alert('Changed data object to "c". Object changed, attribute still "b".\rData Attribute: ' + $d.attr('data-test') + '\rData Object: ' + $d.data('test'));
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/F5qkq/

So in your case, you only change the data attribute with `attr` but that way the internal data-object remains the same because they aren't connected anymore.

The data-attribute is only really used to initialize the data object with a startvalue. But after that, as said before, you should only work with jQuery's `data` function to change the internal data object.

Comment: But, it doesn't modify it in the DOM, and everytime the thumb is clicked, I re-read the coords from the DOM. So shouldn't it not matter?